# Convergence of a product series with one $1/k$ factor

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series, divergent-series

Let $\left( a_n \right)_n$ be a sequence such that $a_n < 1$, $a_n \rightarrow 0$.

Prove or disprove (with a counter-example) that
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n} < \infty.$$

Comments. If there exists $c, e>0$ such that $a_n \leq c/n^e$ for all $n$, than we get the upper bound $c \sum_n 1/n^{1+e} < \infty$. But I am not sure that such $c, e$ always exist. Does $a_n = 1/\log(n)$ disprove the convergence?

Comment: You need to modify your $a_n$ so that $a_n \leqslant 1$, so you can't take $\frac{1}{\log n}$ for $n\in \{1,2\}$. But then, does $$\sum_{n = 3}^\infty \frac{1}{n\log n}$$ converge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idea:

Take $\;a_n:=\dfrac1{\log n}\;,\;\;n\ge3$ .

You might also want to use the [Condensation Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) to check stuff with the resulting series.

Answer (score 0):

Use integral test, since $1/n\ln n\to 0$ and is decreasing, the convergence of $\sum 1/n\ln n$ is the same as $\int_{2}^{+\infty} dx/x\ln x$...

Comment: @TravisJ sorry. I'll fix